# Jenkins fails to post build status to gitlab,Pipelines shows up pending status.This is a multibranch pipeline

Tags: gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, devops, multibranch-pipeline

I tried all the possible solutions available online. Changed my token with all permissions. Changed the gitlab connection with latest token. Still pipelines in gitlab shows the pending status. These are the logs from jenkins.

```
Mar 23, 2022 5:37:19 PM INFO com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.util.CommitStatusUpdater retrieveGitlabProjectIds
Retrieving gitlab project ids
Mar 23, 2022 5:37:19 PM WARNING com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.util.CommitStatusUpdater retrieveGitlabProjectIds
No gitlab client found.
Mar 23, 2022 5:38:13 PM INFO com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.util.CommitStatusUpdater retrieveGitlabProjectIds
Retrieving gitlab project ids
Mar 23, 2022 5:38:13 PM WARNING com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.util.CommitStatusUpdater retrieveGitlabProjectIds
No gitlab client found.
Mar 23, 2022 5:38:13 PM INFO com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.util.CommitStatusUpdater retrieveGitlabProjectIds
Retrieving gitlab project ids
Mar 23, 2022 5:38:13 PM WARNING com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.util.CommitStatusUpdater retrieveGitlabProjectIds
No gitlab client found.
Mar 23, 2022 5:38:14 PM INFO com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.util.CommitStatusUpdater retrieveGitlabProjectIds
Retrieving gitlab project ids
Mar 23, 2022 5:38:14 PM WARNING com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.util.CommitStatusUpdater retrieveGitlabProjectIds
No gitlab client found.
Mar 23, 2022 5:38:14 PM INFO com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.util.CommitStatusUpdater retrieveGitlabProjectIds
Retrieving gitlab project ids
Mar 23, 2022 5:38:14 PM WARNING com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.util.CommitStatusUpdater retrieveGitlabProjectIds
No gitlab client found.
Mar 23, 2022 5:38:14 PM INFO com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.util.CommitStatusUpdater retrieveGitlabProjectIds
Retrieving gitlab project ids
Mar 23, 2022 5:38:14 PM WARNING com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.util.CommitStatusUpdater retrieveGitlabProjectIds
No gitlab client found.
Mar 23, 2022 5:38:15 PM INFO org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun finish
multi/pipelines-check #79 completed: SUCCESS
Mar 23, 2022 5:38:15 PM INFO io.jenkins.plugins.generic.event.HttpEventSender send
Skipped event sending due to receiver URL not set
Mar 23, 2022 5:38:16 PM WARNING jenkins.util.Listeners lambda$notify$0
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.jenkins.plugins.gitlabbranchsource.helpers.GitLabPipelineStatusNotifier.lambda$getStatusName$0(GitLabPipelineStatusNotifier.java:102)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:1050)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.gitlabbranchsource.helpers.GitLabPipelineStatusNotifier.getStatusName(GitLabPipelineStatusNotifier.java:101)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.gitlabbranchsource.helpers.GitLabPipelineStatusNotifier.getStatusName(GitLabPipelineStatusNotifier.java:84)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.gitlabbranchsource.helpers.GitLabPipelineStatusNotifier.logComment(GitLabPipelineStatusNotifier.java:178)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.gitlabbranchsource.helpers.GitLabPipelineStatusNotifier.access$500(GitLabPipelineStatusNotifier.java:52)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.gitlabbranchsource.helpers.GitLabPipelineStatusNotifier$JobCompletedListener.onCompleted(GitLabPipelineStatusNotifier.java:484)
    at hudson.model.listeners.RunListener.lambda$fireCompleted$0(RunListener.java:207)
    at jenkins.util.Listeners.lambda$notify$0(Listeners.java:59)
    at jenkins.util.Listeners.notify(Listeners.java:67)
    at hudson.model.listeners.RunListener.fireCompleted(RunListener.java:205)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.finish(WorkflowRun.java:627)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.access$800(WorkflowRun.java:138)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun$GraphL.onNewHead(WorkflowRun.java:1049)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.notifyListeners(CpsFlowExecution.java:1474)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$3.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:497)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$1.run(CpsVmExecutorService.java:38)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

JENKINSFILE:

```
pipeline {
  agent {label 'xxx'}
  options {
     gitLabConnection('xxx')
          }

  stages {
     stage('Code') {
            steps {
            gitlabCommitStatus(connection:     gitLabConnection(gitLabConnection: 'xxx', jobCredentialId: 'xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx', useAlternativeCredential: true), name: 'Code_checkout') {
          checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/develop']], extensions: [[$class: 'GitLFSPull'], [$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'xxxxxx']], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'git@gitlab.com:xxxxx/xxxxxx/root.git']]])
              sh'''
              cd xxxxxxxxx
              git submodule update --init --recursive
              cd /home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/ROOT/vds
              git checkout develop
              git pull
              cd xxxxxxxxxxx
              '''
              }
            }
     }
     stage('Testing') {
            steps {
                gitlabCommitStatus(connection:     gitLabConnection(gitLabConnection: 'xxxxxx', jobCredentialId: 'xxxxxxx', useAlternativeCredential: true), name: 'Testing') {
                echo "checking"
            }
        }
   }
  }
```

all the code checkout part and testing part is happening in shell

Comment: can you paste you jenkinsfile here? so we can get better understanding on problem that you are having

Comment: @DashrathMundkar Jenkinsfile added. Its a simple jenkins  pipeline. Because we have dockerised the test and all the tests are happening in the docker

Comment: Skipped event sending due to receiver URL not set
 jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchIndexing run
Single-repo #20220325.152422 branch indexing action completed: SUCCESS in 7.2 sec
com.igalg.jenkins.plugins.mswt.trigger.ComputedFolderWebHookTrigger 
setting token:xxx
com.igalg.jenkins.plugins.mswt.trigger.ComputedFolderWebHookTrigger 
setting token:xxx
io.jenkins.plugins.gitlabbranchsource.GitLabHookCreator createSystemHookWhenMissing
User is not admin so cannot set system hooks
org.gitlab4j.api.GitLabApiException: 403 Forbidden

Comment: Error remains same

Answer (score 2):

You can use these two parameters in `options`block

```
options {
    gitLabConnection('gitlab')
    gitlabBuilds(builds: ['build'])
}
```

and in post section you can use the `updateGitlabCommitStatus` like this

```
post {
    failure {
      updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'build', state: 'failed'
    }
    unstable {
      updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'build', state: 'failed'
    }
    aborted {
      updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'build', state: 'canceled'
    }
    success {
      updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'build', state: 'success'
    }
    always {
    }
}
```

For info checkout this section https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/blob/master/README.md